# NumPy error when importing ArcPy in virtual environment with ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2

Tags: python, arcpy, numpy, virtualenv

In many projects I use a Python virtual environment with ArcPy. I always use the same method to for setup:

1. Create a virtual environment
2. In the `site-packages` directory, add a file named Desktop10.X.pth with the following content:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.X\bin                
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.x\ArcPy              
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.x\ArcToolBox\Scripts 
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x\Lib\site-packages
```

Until recently, this solution used to work without any problems. But since my organization upgraded ArcGIS Desktop from 10.8 to 10.8.2, I get this error every time I try to `import arcpy`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using C:\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This problem occurs both in my existing environments (which used to work before 10.8.2) and in newly created environments.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with NumPy when installing packages into my ArcGIS Python environment. It caused about 50% of my geoprocessing tools to stop working completely. Repairing the installation didn't work. I know it's not the most desirable, but the only thing that fixed it for me was uninstalling and reinstalling completely.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you will need to uninstall and reinstall, but there is a small chance that you may get it to work if you do the following:

1. Delete your virtual environment.
2. Upgrade `numpy` in the master environment. Use ArcGIS Pro if possible.
3. If the upgrade in ArcGIS Pro doesn't work or isn't available, try [doing the same in `conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html).
4. If that doesn't work, try [doing the same in `pip`](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-usage/).
5. If that doesn't work, try to uninstall and reinstall `numpy`, first through `conda` then `pip`.
6. If anything along the way changed, try to spin a new virtual environment and see if it works any better.

The package name across the board *should* be `numpy` without any version material, punctuation, etc. That makes things slightly easier.

I understand that these steps are annoying, meandering and repetitive, **however** you *should* be able to do them without administrator permissions. This is also slightly less intrusive than killing your entire ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap installation.